# How to correct my gmdate method?

Tags: php

My code is working but the only thing `$todaystamp` shows 3 hours before my clock time. And I wanna fix it. (GMT+3) I still want to use `gmdate` method because I don't know how to change the rest of... How can I do it without broke my other codes? thanks...

```
  <?php


    function sendIcalEmail($firstname,$lastname,$email,$meeting_date,$meeting_name,$meeting_duration,$message1,$place1) {

        $from_name = "Furkan Öksüz";
        $from_address = "furk.oksuz4@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Olusturulan Etkinlik"; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
        $meeting_description = $message1;
        $meeting_location = $place1; //Where will your meeting take place

        //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
        $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . " UTC"); 
        $dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
        $dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
        $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime("+3 hours"));





        $cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";

        //Create Mime Boundry
        $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());

        //Create Email Headers
        $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
        $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

        //Create Email Body (HTML)
        $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

        $message .= "<html>\n";
        $message .= "<body>\n";
        $message .= '<p>Merhaba '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>';
        $message .= $message1;    
        $message .= "</body>\n";
        $message .= "</html>\n";
        $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";




     $ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    METHOD:PUBLISH
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
    DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
    DTEND:'.$dtend.'
    LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    SEQUENCE:0
    UID:'.$cal_uid.'
    DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
    DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
    SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
    PRIORITY:5
    CLASS:PUBLIC
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR';   

        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $message .= $ical;            

        //SEND MAIL
        $mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

        if($mail_sent)     {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }   

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: What is the timezone set in your PHP? Why do you convert $meeting_date from UTC? Is that really what you want?

Comment: Also, please, clear up the unrelated code parts and write what are the input and "output" values - dumps of `$meetingstamp` and `$todaystamp`.